# Godot doesn't loop the sound

Tags: godot, sound-effects

Basically it's the sound of a fuse for a bomb, until the timer sends the signal the sound should stop playing and play the explosion sound, but right now only plays once and the stop.

What i did wrong/ what i did missed?

the code i use for the bomb scene:

```
extends StaticBody2D

func _ready():
    $AnimatedSprite.animation = "bomb"
    $CollisionShape2D.disabled = true
    $BombTimer.start()
    $FuseSound.play()

func _on_BombTimer_timeout():
    $AnimatedSprite.animation = "explosion"
    $CollisionShape2D.disabled = false
    $RemoveTimer.start()
    $ExplosionSound.play()

func _on_RemoveTimer_timeout():
    queue_free()

func _on_Bomb_body_entered(body):
    print("bomb collided with:" + body.get_name())
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you click the "Reimport" button after checking "Loop" in the import dock? Also, I'm not sure if you should touch "Loop End" manually in the inspector.

Comment: if i let "loop end" with 0, no sound can be heard when playing the game

Comment: Can you try $ExplosionSound.stream.set_loop(true) in the _ready function ?